# $\int 1/\sin(x)\ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to find $\int 1/\sin(x)\ dx$, but I can't figure out how to do it.  Also, what would be the value of
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin x} dx\quad ?$$
Based on symmetry, I would try to say it is zero, but I've been told to be careful when integrating functions that diverge to $\infty$ in the range of integration.

Comment: $dx{}{}{}$, yes?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function) on the integral of the secant function is a great read.

Comment: You might also find [this](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m103/mercator/mercator.html) interesting.

Comment: @AndrewChin Yes, but some of the formulas become $\infty - \infty$ when evaluating the definite integral.

Comment: The improper integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ diverges.

Comment: The Cauchy principal value is 0 (this is a manifestation of the symmetry)

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think that's the way I would need to make sense of that expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By just checking the left end point only we already see the integral diverges. This is because on the interval $[0,2\pi]$,
$$ |\! \sin x| \leq x \implies \left|\frac{1}{\sin x} \right| \geq \frac1x ,$$
and the above leads us to
$$ \int_0^{2 \pi} \left| \frac{1}{\sin x} \right| dx \geq \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac1x dx .$$
The later integral diverges, so by comparison test the former also diverges.

Comment: You need absolute values, because $\sin$ is negative for $\pi < x < 2\pi$.

Comment: Yes indeed. My first intention was to make a intuitive argument by considering only near the left end point. I will amend my answer to make it rigorous.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\;t=\tan \cfrac x2\;$ for $\;x\in(-\pi,\pi)\;$ then $\;\sin x = \cfrac{2t}{1+t^2}\;$ and $\;\mathrm dx=\cfrac 2{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt$ \begin{align}\therefore \int\frac{1}{\sin x}\,\mathrm dx &= \int\cfrac 1{\big(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\big)}\cdot\cfrac 2{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt \\ &=\int\cfrac 1t\,\mathrm dt \\ &=\ln |t|+c \\ &=\ln \bigg|\tan \cfrac x2\bigg|+c\end{align}